# Is it possible to capture output from a system command and redirect it?

Tags: ruby, shell, pipe

What I would like to do is:

1. run a ruby script...
2. that executes a shell command
3. and redirects it to a named pipe accessible outside the script
4. from the system shell, read from that pipe

That is, have the Ruby script capture some command output and redirect it in such a way that it's connectable to from outside the script?

I want to mention that the script cannot simply start and exit, since it's a REPL. The idea is that using the REPL you would be able to run a command and redirect its output elsewhere to consume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `abort` and an exit message, will pass the message to STDERR (and the script will fail with exit code 1).  You can pass this shell command output in this way.

This is possibly not the only (or best) way, but it has worked for me in the past.

[edit]

You can also redirect the output to a file (using standard methods), and read that file outside the ruby script.

Comment: That's not going to work for me unfortunately, since the script needs to keep running. I should have mentioned that it's a REPL. I will update the question. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, I think it might be! I started dabbling with a named pipe and I think that might in fact be the best option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open3'
stdin, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(commandline)
stdin.chomp #Here, you should ge
```

Incase, if someone wanted to use you can get the output via stdin.chomp